# output a html table data to excel using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have a html table that has some data in it, now i want to output this data to e excel but i dont know how to to do this. I have search some posts but i cant figure out how it works. How i can import the data? this is my code so far.. Thanks for the help

```
echo "<table id='pagesat' style='width:1000px;margin-top:10px;'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>OPERATORI</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>KONTRATA</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>ORE PUNE</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>REZE</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>PAGA BRUTO</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>SIGURIME<br>PUNE MARRESI</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>TAP</th>
                        <th><img id='img' src='images/sort.png'>PAGA NETO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            ";
            $totPaga = 0;
        foreach($kontratat as $key => $value){
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$fullName."</td>
                    <td>".$rezultati[$key]."</td>
                    <td>".$kontratat_ore[$key]."</td>
                    <td>".$rese."</td>
                    <td>".$Pagesa_ndare.' lek'."</td>
                    <td>".$sigurime_vlera.' lek'."</td>
                    <td>".$vlera_tap_perfund.' lek'."</td>
                    <td>".$paga_neto_perf.' lek'."</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    }

}
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'OPERATORI')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'KONTRATA')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'ORE PUNE')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'REZE')
    ->setCellValue('E1', 'PAGA BRUTO');



    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="EGEO_PAGA.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's far easier to build the Excel directly rather than outputtig html markup and then hoping to read that

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer. Do you have any link or a ecample that could help me with that? Thanks again!

Comment: There's a mass of [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) and [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) with PHPExcel that shows how to store data in cells